# Using a custom F# operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, operators, clr

I've stumbled upon the fact that it's possible to define custom operators in F#. Also, I believe it's possible to reuse F# code in C#.

Is it possible to create a custom operator in F#, reference the project in C# and then reuse the operator in C#? For example, lets say I were to define the `.?` operator as something in F#, could I then somehow reuse it in my C# projects?

Comment: As the answers point out, you can, but you will only be able to use it from C# as a method, not an operator, of course.

Comment: Shame, but it'll have to do. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Custom defined operators can be used just fine from C#. The names are auto-generated and are of the form `op_<symbol...>` (see [*Overloaded Operator Names*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx) on MSDN).

For example

```
let (|?) a b = ...
```

would be available as `op_BarQmark`.

However, as Mau points out in his comment, *you will only be able to use it from C# as a method, not an operator*.

Comment: @Benjol: Regarding your edit, I thought it was apparent based on the names that they don't appear as operators in C# (Mau says as much in his comment: _"as the answers point out"_). But I suppose it doesn't hurt to make it explicit.